# Implementing a very efficient bit structure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory, pseudocode

I'm looking for a solution in pesudo code or java or js for the following problem:

We need to implement an efficient bit structure to hold data for N bits (you could think of the bits as booleans as well, on/off).

We need to support the following methods:
init(n)
get(index)
set(index, True/False)
setAll(True/false)

Now I got to a solution  with o(1) in all  except for init that is o(n). The idea was to create an array where each index saves value for a bit. In order to support the setAll I would also save a timestamp withe the bit vapue to know if to take the value from tge array or from tge last setAll value. The o(n) in init is because we need to go through the array to nullify it, otherwise it will have garbage which can be ANYTHING. Now I was asked to find a solution where the init is also o(1) (we can create an array, but we cant clear the garbage, the garbage might even look like valid data which is wrong and make the solution bad, we need a solution that works 100%).

Update:
This is an algorithmic qiestion and not a language specific one. I encountered it in an interview question. Also using an integer to represent the bit array is not good enough because of memory limits. I was tipped that it has something to do with some kind of smart handling of garbage data in the array without ckeaning it in the init, using some kind of mechanism to not fall because if the garbage data in the array (but I'm not sure how).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: By reading the first paragraph I can ser it doesn't meet the question restrictions. It says it inits the vector to have false for all bits, which is what my solution also doing which is o(n). Not goid enough for this question

Comment: You say you need it to be efficient, but you only quote asymptotic complexity requirements. `HashMap<Integer, Boolean>` gives you O(1) init, get, set, and you can wrap it with a `boolean inverted;` to implement SetAll as O(1).

Comment: In Java, an array is guaranteed to be initialized with zeros (the same applies for the `BitSet`), so you don't have to initialize it *manually*. Of course, the initialization is still "O(n)", strictly speaking. But this is almost certainly negligible compared to the allocation itself, and any more sophisticated data structure will increase the constant of the O(1) operations anyhow.

Comment: The question focuses on an algorithmic approach and not to a specific programming language, for this purpose the init when you need to null an array is o(n). I'm looking for an answer under this assumptions that isn't programming focused.

Comment: I was told to consider the allocation as O(1) for the sake of this question though.

Comment: Similar to `BitSet` class, you could look at [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) and [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) when the domain of values is known at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Make **lazy** data structure based on hashmap (while hashmap sometimes might have worse access time than o(1)) with 32-bit values *(8,16,64 ints are suitable too)* for storage and auxiliary field `InitFlag`

To clear all, make empty map with `InitFlag = 0`  (deleting old map is GC's work in Java, isn't it?)

To set all, make empty map with `InitFlag = 1`

When changing some bit, check whether corresponding int key `bitnum/32` exists. If yes, just change `bitnum&32` bit, if not and bit value differs from `InitFlag` -  create key with value based on `InitFlag` (all zeros or all ones) and change needed bit.

When retrieving some bit, check whether corresponding key exists. If yes, extract bit, if not - get `InitFlag` value

```
SetAll(0):   ifl = 0, map - {}
SetBit(35):   ifl = 0, map - {1 : 0x10}
SetBit(32):   ifl = 0, map - {1 : 0x12}
ClearBit(32):   ifl = 0, map - {1 : 0x10}
ClearBit(1):   do nothing, ifl = 0, map - {1 : 0x10}
GetBit(1):     key=0 doesn't exist,  return ifl=0
GetBit(35):     key=1 exists,  return map[1]>>3 =1
SetAll(1):      ifl = 1, map = {}
SetBit(35):     do nothing
ClearBit(35):   ifl = 1, map - {1 : 0xFFFFFFF7 = 0b...11110111}
and so on
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your solution (I have no idea what you are doing with the map) but if you use an integer to store the bits, then you are pimited by the int size which makes it a wrong answer.  Also a map is based on array in this kind of questions, so in o(1) your array will have garbage values

Comment: 1 int stores 32 bits, K ints store 32*K bits :)   Imagine you have an array int[], but really change only few entries after intilaization. Map stores only these entries (index as key, array item as value)

Comment: Well then I just really don't understand your answer :/

Comment: Perhaps my description is not well (while approach is tricky). What is unclear?

Comment: I thought of doing this with only ints, and in several levels. Problem is that then you could argue that the get and set operations are not O(1) but O(logN). Which would technically be true, but it could be O(Log64(N)) which would give you a billion bits in 5 steps. Similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522165/efficient-data-structure-for-storing-a-long-sequence-of-mostly-consecutive-int/39606245#39606245

Comment: @m69 Why get/set is O(logN)? "Interviewers" usually rely on supposition that hashmap time is O(1) in average. Bit access is O(1) for machine words.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood your answer, and it's not similar to what I wanted to suggest. I wasn't talking about hashmaps, but about using e.g. a 64-bit int to represent each 1/64th of the range, and then (when a part of the range is not all 0 or 1) an int to represent 1/4096ths of the range, and so on. That would mean e.g. 5 layers if the range is 1 billion. So setting and getting would take Log64(range) steps.

Comment: @m69 Here structure is plain and ranges are not involved. The main thing is delayed physical data creation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a college/high-school computer science test or homework assignment question - I suspect they are trying to get you to use **BOOLEAN BIT-WISE LOGIC** - specifically, saving the bit inside of an int or a long.  I suspect (but I'm not a mind-reader - and I could be wrong!) that using "Arrays" is ***exactly*** what your teacher would want you to avoid.

For instance - this quote is copied from Google's Search Reults:

> **long:** The **long data type** is a ***64-bit two's complement integer***. The
>   signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1.
>   In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an
>   unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum
>   value of 264-1

What that means is that a single long variable in Java could store 64 of your bit-wise values:

```
long storage;
// To get the first bit-value, use logical-or ('|') and get the bit.
boolean result1 = (boolean) storage | 0b00000001; // Gets the first bit in 'storage'
boolean result2 = (boolean) storage | 0b00000010; // Gets the second
boolean result3 = (boolean) storage | 0b00000100; // Gets the third
...
boolean result8 = (boolean) storage | 0b10000000; // Gets the eighth result.
```

I could write the entire thing for you, but I'm not 100% sure of your actual specifications - if you use a long, you can only store 64 separate binary values.  If you want an arbitrary number of values, you would have to use as many 'long' as you need.

Here is a SO posts about binary / boolean values:
[Binary representation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593401/binary-representation-in-java)

Here is a SO post about bit-shifting:
[Java - Circular shift using bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844084/java-circular-shift-using-bitwise-operations)

Again, it would be a job, and I'm not going to write the entire project.  However, the `get(int index)` and `set(int index, boolean val)` methods would involve bit-wise shifting of the number 1.

```
int pos = 1;
pos = pos << 5;  // This would function as a 'pointer' to the fifth element of the binary number list.
storage | pos;  // This retrieves the value stored as position 5.
```

Comment: I've implemented these concepts a while back; have a look: https://github.com/rslemos/bitsmagic/blob/develop/src/main/java/br/eti/rslemos/bitsmagic/Store.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought of this when I encountered the question. I asked the the interviewer and this was not the intention (because using an integer is limited because of memory space for it).